# Wordpress Update error ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to update my Wordpress Core to 4.2.1, but I had an error :

I fill my FTP account, as usual, and the update process begin :

```
Téléchargement de la mise à jour depuis https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.2.1-partial-0.zip…

Décompression de la mise à jour…

Vérification des fichiers décompressés…

Préparation de l’installation de la dernière version…

Activation du mode maintenance…
```

And, when the last line appears, my Chrome development console output :

```
POST http://***/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-core-upgrade&_wpnonce=f147e3840e net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

And the process stops. The update is not done.

I tried to update my extensions first, it didn't worked either, but the process changed a little.

I filled my FTP account, then I get an direct error :

```
POST http://***/wp-admin/update.php?action=update-selected&plugins=akism…k-cache%2Fquick-cache.php%2Cwordpress-seo%2Fwp-seo.php&_wpnonce=f0044a07f9 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I've done some checkings :

- The root directory is owned by the FTP account
- The /wp-content/ is in chmod 777

Can somebody help me please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with wp_tempnam(), as suggested to me [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32162), use [this patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/32135/32135-1.diff)!

Comment: Thank you so much, that works for the core update. Not for the plugin update so, but I will find a way trough the Wordpress Forum.